# !grep for more than one pattern R

Tags: r, grepl

I have a df of:

```
A <- c(10,14,45,3687)
B <- c(354,587,45,6787)
C <- c("I","J","K","L")

df <- data.frame(A,B,C)
```

I want to subset this df by NOT matching on more than one pattern in column C.
(I know it is easier to match but I need to find a way to not match).
I have tried:

```
no_K_L <- df[!grepl(c("K"|"L"), df$C),]
```

but R says:
'operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types'

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to concatenate.. Try the following

```
df[!grepl("K|L", df$C),]
   A   B C
1 10 354 I
2 14 587 J
```

Answer (score 0):

to be able to apply this to any number of patterns you don't want to match, define the patterns you don't want to match in a vector using

```
rem_pat <- c("K","L")
```

then "|"-collapse this in your subset command using paste with

```
(no_K_L <- df[!grepl(paste(rem_pat, collapse = "|"), df$C),])
   A   B C
1 10 354 I
2 14 587 J
```